# How to properly convert CameraImage so that I can send it to a websocket server?

Tags: flutter, image, websocket

I would like to continously send images to a websocket server from my flutter application.

I set up the app to do something with the camera stream every N seconds.

However, unlike just taking a photo with the cameracontroller, I can not send it to the websocket server as I've previously read it CameraImage uses a different encoding.

How can I convert it so that I can work with it in advance?

This is my current code, for now I set up taking pictures with the cameraController every 5 seconds, but this gives a bad, laggy user experience.

```
_cameraController?.startImageStream((CameraImage image) {
      if (_frameProcessingTimer == null || !_frameProcessingTimer!.isActive) {
        _frameProcessingTimer =
            Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) async {
          try {
            final image = await _cameraController!.takePicture();
            // Read the image file as bytes
            final bytes = await File(image.path).readAsBytes();

            channel.sink.add(bytes);
          } catch (e) {
            print('Error sending image to server: $e');
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

I've seen some posts on stackoverflow asking this question, but the answers there use 3+ year old solutions that mostly didn't work because of syntax errors and I'm wondering if there is a newer solution to this problem.